# Global Variable Resetting On Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a variable `CURRENTUSER` in `GlobalVariable.cs`:

[GlobalVariables.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WagRO.png)

It is modified in `LoginPage.xaml.cs`:

[LoginPage.xaml.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiuXx.png)

And after navigating to `ConceptForm.xaml.cs`, it is called a few times:

```
public partial class ConceptForm : Page
{
    //Default Constructor
    public ConceptForm()
    {
        //Initializing the Default Constructor
        InitializeComponent();

        //Debugging Code To Indicate Current Signed In User
         string cU = GlobalVariables.**CURRENTUSER**.ToString();
         MessageBox.Show(cU);

        //Get Current User Name Based On login credentials 
        campaignProductManagerBox.Text = campaignProductManagerBox.Text + GlobalVariables.USERS[GlobalVariables.**CURRENTUSER**, 2];

        //Get Current Date And Time
        DateTime dAT = DateTime.Now;
        dateAndTimeBox.Text = dateAndTimeBox.Text + dAT;

        //Get Current User Phone Number Based On Login Credentials
        contactNumberBox.Text = contactNumberBox.Text + GlobalVariables.USERS[GlobalVariables.**CURRENTUSER**, 4];

        //Conditional to determine Quarter of the Year Based On Date And Time Gotten Earlier
        //If current month is January, February or March
        if ( dAT.Month == 1 || dAT.Month == 2 || dAT.Month == 3 )
        {
            //It is the First Quarter of the Year
            conceptIdBox.Text = conceptIdBox.Text + "Q1_";
        }

        //If current month is April, May or June
        else if (dAT.Month == 4 || dAT.Month == 5 || dAT.Month == 6 )
        {
            //It is the Second Quarter of the Year
            conceptIdBox.Text = conceptIdBox.Text + "Q2_";
        }

        //If current month is July, August or September
        else if (dAT.Month == 7 || dAT.Month == 8 || dAT.Month == 9)
        {
            //It is the Third Quarter of the Year
            conceptIdBox.Text = conceptIdBox.Text + "Q3_";
        }

        else
        {
            //It is the Fourth Quarter of the Year
            conceptIdBox.Text = conceptIdBox.Text + "Q2_";
        }

        //Get Current User Department Based On Login Credentials
        conceptIdBox.Text = conceptIdBox.Text + GlobalVariables.USERS[GlobalVariables.**CURRENTUSER**, 3] + "_0";
    }
```

However, the value of `CURRENTUSER` is resetting to `0` after navigating to `ConceptForm.xaml.cs`

I got further proof of this by doing some debugging in `LoginPage.xaml.cs` and `ConceptForm.xaml.cs` which told me that on clicking `Login` on `LoginPage.xaml.cs`, the value of `CURRENTUSER` is `1` which is correct based on the login credentials provided, but as `ConceptForm.xaml.cs` loads, it tells me that `CURRENTUSER` is now `0` which is incorrect.

This is causing the wrong information to be displayed on `ConceptForm.xaml.cs` wherever `CURRENTUSER` is depended upon for the information displayed.

What am I doing wrong, please?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Navigating to a new form will not change the static data. 
Since it is a static member, it has only one instance throughout your program. A static member is not changed unless you set  it forcefully `GlobalVariables.CURRENTUSER = 0`. ie You're setting its value at some point in your code. You may not get a proper answer for this question as you need to debug the code yourself and find out the solution.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Comment: ASP.NET has authentication built in, why not use that?

Comment: @PeterMorris This is a XAML application - desktop, not ASP.Net

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to that CURRENTUSER declaration, right-mouse click and execute "Find All References" - is a value assigned in an unexpected place?

Comment: No idea why I missed the XAML part of the filename :) Make sure your GlobalVariables class is static, and put a getter/setter on the CURRENTUSER, then you can put a break line on the setter and see what is changing it.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers! The problem has been solved. Turns out all I needed to do, was to newly instantiate `ConceptForm.xaml.cs` when I was calling it in `LoginPage.xaml.cs`. So, Instead of `this.NavigationService.Navigate(GlobalVariables.cF);`, it had to be `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new ConceptForm());`. And now, it works like a charm! Again, thank you all for your answers! @IDisposable @Bart @Peter Morris @Hans Kesting